# suppose a function $f$ satisfies the equation $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)+xy^2+yx^2$

Tags: calculus, functional-equations

Suppose a function  $f$ satisfies the equation $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)+xy^2+yx^2$ for all real numbers $x$ and $y$, and $\lim \limits _{x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{f(x)}{x}=1$. Find 1.$f(0)$,  2.$f^\prime (0)$,  3.$f^\prime (x)$

In my solution I started with number 3, I have $f^\prime (x)=1+x^2$. To answer number 2, I just substituted and got $f^\prime (0)=1$. Now coming to number 1, I expected $f(0)$ to be $x$, but using the given equation, I get $f(0)=0$ which contradicts the solution to number 2. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Oh, I see! Thanks

Comment: Ah, no I see the confusion. Did you think like this : $f'(0) = 1$, the anti-derivative of $1$ is $x$, so $f(0) =x$? This is fascinating if so, even as an innocuous mistake.

Answer (score 2):

There is no contradiction; $f(0)$ cannot be a *variable* $x$. $f(0)$ *is* indeed $0$.